# Why does't this toggle and filter not work in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a v-for directive and I am now trying to add a dropdown filter in order to filter the results displayed. However, it's just not working. I have followed every step carefully as this is based on a Treehouse tutorial, but for some reason when changing the dropdown nothing displays. Seems the name property value is not being set to the object. Every time a new option is chosen it should fire the function filterList.

```
const clubs = [
    {
   name: 'Tigers',
   location: 'Manchester',
   members: '22',
   registered: 'No',
   pitch: 'Grass'
    },
    {
   name: 'Dolphins',
   location: 'Miami',
   members: '19',
   registered: 'Yes',
   pitch: 'Grass'
    },
    {
   name: 'Bleu Sox',
   location: 'Paris',
   members: '13',
   registered: 'Yes',
   pitch: 'Astroturf'   
    } 
];

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    clubs,
    name: ''
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDetails: function(club) {
      this.$set(club, 'showDetails', !club.showDetails)
    },
    filterList: function() {
      this.name = event.target.value;
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
});
```

My HTML is as follows;

```
<div id="app">

    <select v-on:change="filterList">
       <option v-for="club in clubs">{{club.name}}</option>
    </select>

  <ul>
    <li v-show="name === club.name" v-for="club in clubs" v-on:click="toggleDetails(club)">
      <h1>{{club.name}}</h1>
      <div v-show="club.showDetails">
          <p>{{club.location}}</p>
          <p>{{club.members}}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to access DOM events for this - Vue is reactive and will update `name` when this is changed:

```
<select v-model="name">
   <option v-for="club in clubs">{{club.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Interesting. So it seems <select v-model="name"> is more robust as it works without including 'event' in the function(event). Where as if you use <select v-on:change="filterList"> from the tutorial I'm following and forget the 'event' it falls apart.